# What to consider when writing distribution-independent Linux applications?

Tags: linux, systemd

I wish to write a graphical tool with which one could configure and query information about a Linux system.
In order to achieve some independence from the underlying Linux distribution, I am planning to require that the target system uses systemd, and that the target system has the PackageKit console program installed.
With this, I will have excluded Slackware Linux, since it does not use systemd.

What other considerations should I have in mind when designing such a tool? With the use of an abstraction layer away from the package manager, and with the use of systemd, are there any other things that I would have to consider?

Comment: I often don't have an X server, and don't have bash installed

Comment: Mainly, just make sure you statically link all the code you are using.

Comment: maybe look at AppImage

Comment: This question is too broad as written: it's impossible to identify a "correct" answer, and most answers are simply going to be matters of opinion. Write your code, and if you run into specific problems, this would be a great place to discuss potential solutions.